# Сохранится ли файл в Google colab, если я выйду из браузера?

Tags: google-colaboratory

Сохранится ли файл в Google colab, если я выйду из браузера?
И еще, можно ли ускорить процесс загрузки?

Comment: И еще))) Можно ли взять лишь маленький участок, скачиваемого файла?

Comment: Лично у меня сейчас не сохранился. (Хотя может я просто глюк какой-то  словил) Относительно второго вопроса - лучше задать по нему отдельный вопрос.